# Prove: If $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow Y$ has a continuous extension to all $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $f_\ast$ is trivial.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove: If $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and has a continuous extension to all $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $f_\ast$ is trivial.

I'm not sure how the fact that there exists an extension changes anything with regards to the fundamental group. I though of a contradictory example, which is problably wrong, but I don't understand why it's wrong:

$X = [0,100]$ , $ Y = S^1$ and $f = (\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Of course $f$ has a continous extension to all $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't see why $f_\ast$ should be trivial. After all, $f$ loops around the circle several times..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your example $f_*$ is trivial since $X$ is simply connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What homotopy would take a loop that goes around the circle a couple of times to constant? Would it just be peeling back the loop? Why cant that work with a punctured disk in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f: X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$ is continuous it induces a homomorphism $f_*: \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$. However if $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$ extends $f$ then we have that $F_*: \{1\} \to \pi_1(Y)$ is certainly trivial because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible. But this gives a nullhomotopy of $f(\gamma)$ for every $\gamma: I \to X$ where $H: I \times I \to Y$ is just the nullhomotopy furnished by the map of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I still don't understand is why the fact that $F_\ast$ is trivial imply that $f_\ast$ is trivial.

Comment: That is the only difficult part of this argument in some sense. Because $F_*$ is trivial we know that every loop $\gamma: S^1 \to X$ goes to some $F \circ \gamma: S^1 \to Y$ and that this $F \circ \gamma$ must be nullhomotopic because it is $F_*([1])$, but if $F|_X = f$ then we know that all the $f \circ \gamma: S^1 \to Y$ are nullhomotopic as well.

Comment: Make sense now?

Comment: Why does $f \circ \gamma$ being nullhomotopic imply that $f$ is nullhomotpic?

Comment: It doesn't mean that, it means that the induced homomorphism on fundamental groups is trivial. It means that because that is the definition of that homomorphism being trivial.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this.

Comment: Alright. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat f: \Bbb R^n \to Y$ be the extension of $f$ and $i: X \to \Bbb R^n$ be the inclusion. By functorality of $\pi_1$, $f_*=(\hat f \circ i)_*=\hat f_* \circ i_*$.  As $\Bbb R^n$ is contractible, both $\hat f_*$ and $i_*$ are zero (they are maps from and to the trivial group respectively), and therefore $f_*=0$.